# sql_autoload_register not autoloading class

Tags: php

```
Sql_autoload_register

(function ($classname){

   include $classname. ' .php ' ;

});

$objA = new manageuser();
```

> Fatal error. Uncaught Error : Class 'manageuser' not found

Comment: Please post your file structure to check

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\call.php

Comment: Where is located manageuser class file?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are only having issue in autoloading classes according to the part of code you posted.

The correct way to use an anonymous function is:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) {
    include  $classname.'.php';
});
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it, initially I was trying to autoload a class name that was different from the file name.

So I sorted it out and realised that the file name where the class is located should be the same with class name.

Thank you all.